# Rails get list of records in batches with custom order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to display a list of users and information about them. But since there are many users in my database, the SQL is **really** slow. Now I would like to display the users in batches of, say, 100 and then reveal/load more as you click "View more".

How would I go about doing that in practice?

[Note: I have a custom order that should be preserved, so the methods in the Rails Documentation don't really help me]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're effectively looking for pagination. The most commonly used gem for this is [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari).

You give a default page size to a model, in your case users, and then call

`User.page(1)`

to access the first page of results. In your controller this will generally look something like:

`@users = User.order(:name).page params[:page]`

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at this

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property called **limit** and **offset**. with this you can ***limit to tell the number of records to be fetched***, and use ***offset to tell the number of records to skip before starting to return the records***.

example:

```
User.limit(3)  # this returns first three records
```

It will generate following sql query.

```
"SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 3"
```

As offset is not mentioned in above query so it will return first three records.

```
 User.limit(5).offset(30)
#returns 5 records starting from 31th so you will get the records from 31 to 35
```

It will generate following sql query.

```
"SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 5 OFFSET 30"
```